# Hartshorne's Theorem 3.7 chapter III

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I have some small problem with this theorem: Let $X$ be the Noetherian scheme, let $P$ be a closed point of $X$, let $U$ be a neighborhood of $P$ and let $Y=X-U$ then he claims that there is an exact sequence
 $$0\rightarrow \mathcal{T}_{Y\cup \left \{ P \right \}}\rightarrow \mathcal{T}_{Y}\rightarrow k(P)\rightarrow 0$$ where 
$\mathcal{T}_{Y\cup \left \{ P \right \}}, \mathcal{T}_{Y}$ are the ideal sheaves of the closed set $Y\cup \left \{ P \right \},Y$ respectively and the sheaf $k(P)=\mathcal{O}_{X,P}/ \mathfrak{m}_P$ at $P$ and $\mathfrak{m}_P$ is the maximal ideal of the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}$.

I've tried to prove the above sequence is exact. So, I checked on the fibers. For any other point than $P$, it is ok for me but for $P$, I get some trouble. I compute $\mathcal{T}_{Y,P}=\mathcal{O}_{X,P}$ and $k(P)_{P}=\mathcal{O}_{X,P}/ \mathfrak{m}_P$. I guess that $\mathcal{T}_{Y\cup \left \{ P \right \},P}=\mathfrak{m}_P$ but it seems not to be true for me. So, can any give me a hint to solve this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Perhaps it might be easier to work on the open set $U$. The restriction of the ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}_{Y \cup P} |_U$ is the same as $\mathcal{I}_P |_U$. In other words, the ideal sheaves of $Y \cup P$ and $P$ have the same restriction on $U$. Can you see why this is true, and $\mathcal{I}_{P,P} = \mathfrak{m}_P$?

Comment: Because  $Y \cup P \cap U = P$. It is true? But I still have no clue why $\mathcal{T}_{P,P} =\mathfrak{m}_P$ ? Can you give me some hint?

Comment: What do you think is the stalk of an ideal sheaf of a point? (What is the definition?)

Comment: The ideal sheaf $\mathcal{T}_Y$ is the kernel of $\mathcal{O}_X \rightarrow i_* \mathcal{O_Y}$ where $i$ is the inclusion from $Y$ to $X$. And we localize at $P$ and compute the kernel? It is right?

Comment: @AnKhuongDoan I have been trying to work through this same theorem and am having a similar problem. In particular, I am used to dealing with the "ideal sheaf of a closed subscheme", not a closed subset. Indeed for any closed subset we can put many scheme structures on it. So what exactly do you mean by $\mathcal{O}_{Y}$? What is the sheaf structure on $Y$ here?

Comment: @Luke Hi, $Y$ here is equipped with the reduced induced subscheme structure. If you have done exercise 3.11 chapter II, page 92, Hartshorne's book, (especially part c) ) then there will be no problem.